# Why doesn't a Mac Catalyst app use numberOfTouchesRequired?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, mac-catalyst

I'm porting apps from iOS to Mac using Mac Catalyst and noticed that two- and three-finger tap gestures don't work. Here's some example code:

```
UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:test];
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleColumns:)];
gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
gesture.delegate = self;
[test addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

If I tap the red box with two fingers on my Magic Trackpad, nothing happens. The target method isn't called, nor are the gesture delegate methods like `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`. However, if I comment out the `numberOfTouchesRequired` line, then a one-fingered tap works.

I don't see anything about this limitation in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer/1623580-numberoftouchesrequired?language=objc), and apparently it's not a general limit with multi-touch because a UIPinchGestureRecognizer works as expected. Am I missing something, or should I file a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

Mac Catalyst seems to respond to a two finger click to show a `UIContextMenuInteraction`.

If you implement this, you can use this for showing a menu for a two finger click. Here is a [decent tutorial](https://kylebashour.com/posts/ios-13-context-menus).

Note: I am using mac catalyst in "Scale Interface to Match iPad" mode.